# Quill - an unnecessary input field

Tags: quill

After I had saved the quill text and tried to render the text (posts) and present it in the template, I'm getting an unwanted input field.

"Tell me! What are you...." is the quill text:

[image]

I have no idea what this is doing there, I will appreciate any help.

My code:

```
new_post = Post(user=request.user, body=chapter, description=description, deadline=deadline)
new_post.save()
post = Post.objects.get(id = new_post.id)
new_story = Story(title=title, image=image)
new_story.save()
new_story.posts.add(post)
            
 return render(request, "story.html", {
      "user": request.user,
       "title": title,
       "description": description,
       "posts": new_story.posts.all(),
       "genre": genre,
       "deadline": deadline,
       "image": new_story.image 
        })
```

html:

```
<body>
    <h6 id="header">StoryWeave - Story</h6>
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="Story Image">

    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.body|safe }}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {{ genre }} {{ deadline }} {{ user }}

</body>
```